# What kind of convergence actually takes place in the definition of ergodicity?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, ergodic-theory, time-series

We say that the stationary time series $(X_t)_{t \in \mathbb Z}$, , with mean $\mu$, is mean ergodic if the following converge in probability holds:
\begin{equation}\label{a}\tag{M-E}
\hat{\mu}_T := \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T X^t \overset{p}{\to} \mu
\end{equation}

But, others define ergodicity when the converge in \ref{a} holds for other convergence. For example, [here (slide 14)](https://www.lem.sssup.it/phd/documents/Lesson6.pdf) the author uses quadratic mean, and [here (slide 5)](https://web.pdx.edu/%7Ecrkl/ec571/ec571-tsa.pdf), almost sure convergence.

I know well that quadratic mean convergence and almost sure congergence, each one, implies convergence in probability.  So I have no problem defining mean-ergodicity using quadratic mean  convergence or almost sure.

The problem is when it comes to showing that a certain process is not mean-ergodicity. For example, in the [same lecture (slides 19 and 20)](https://www.lem.sssup.it/phd/documents/Lesson6.pdf) given above, it shows that it is not mean-ergodic by showing that quadratic mean convergence does not hold. However, it may still hold convergence in probability. I didn't check if in this case the convergence in probability doesn't hold too, but wouldn't it be better to prove the non-convergence in probability to avoid these cases?

Which convergence to use when showing no-men-ergodicity?